# using 'new' operator

Tags: c++, operators

I have simple task concerning 'new' operator. I need to create array of 10 chars and then input those chars using 'cin'. Should it look like this ? :

```
char c = new char[10];
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> char[i] >> endl;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to dynamically allocate the array? Why do you use a `char` array anyway? Is this part of the requirement of your homework? Otherwise you should definitely use `std::string` instead. If for no other reason, then because _all of the answers so far have a __buffer overflow__ waiting to be exploited_. `std::string` eliminates this danger.

Answer (score 9):

No. Try `char* c = new char[10];`.

Answer (score 5):

char[i] should be c[i]

Answer (score 4):

No need for `endl`. And don't forget to `delete []` the array at the end

Comment: Unless the program just terminates after the code given above

Answer (score 2):

```
char *c = new char[11];  // c should be a pointer.don't forget space for null char.
// do error checking.
cin >> c;                // you can read the entire char array at once.
cout<<c<<endl;           // endl should be used with cout not cin.
delete[]c;               // free the allocated memory.
```

Comment: Why didn't you use also the cin.width() ? Or is it unnecessary here? And why not allocate on the stack?

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody has done yet, I'll suggest you use `std::string` instead:

```
std::string word;
std::cin >> word; // reads everything up to the first whitespace
```

or

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin,line);
```

The advantage of using `std::string` is that it expands automatically, eliminating buffer overflows. If instead you deal with naked character buffers

```
void f()
{
  char buffer[10];
  std::cin >> buffer;
  //
}
```

and someone comes along and enters more than 10 characters, then if you are lucky, the whole thing blows up immediately. (If you are unlucky, everything appears to keep working until some "funny" errors manifest much later, probably in seemingly unrelated sections of your code.)

Comment: I'd imagine this would fail to meet the requirements of the homework assignment, but yea, in most other situations definitely prefer std::string over char*.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach might be:

```
char * c = new char[11];
cin >> c;
```

Comment: @Potatoswatter: agreed about whitespace (which may not matter in this instance), but why do you think it will overflow ?

Comment: If you don't assume that whitespace occurs in the 10-character sequence, the assumption that the 11th character would be whitespace is also unsafe.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: OK - slightly different from the original assertion of "will overflow" then. I was assuming a simple example where he is entering 10 characters and then hitting return.

Comment: I agree with @potatoswatter.  Even in this extremely simple example this particular pattern of code should never be used, unless to illustrate the potential for abuse.  Guarding against buffer overflows should be taught as a fundamental part of programming, as soon as new and delete are introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Close.

```
char *c = new char[10];
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> c[i];
}

// free the memory here somewhere
```

Better yet, if you don't really need a pointer.... don't use one. Then you don't have to worry about memory leaks. (obligatory mention of smart pointers?)

```
char c[10];
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cin >> c[i];
}
```

Or... as others mentioned... read the whole 10 chars in at once. The difference is that with *this* solution spaces are accepted, with `cin >> c` spaces are treated as delimiters IIRC.

Comment: That's the word I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
char c[10];
cin.get( c, 10 );
```

Answer (score 1):

To explain above answers, the "char*" is there because it says that the "c" variable will be a pointer. You need that, because "new" allocates some memory in heap and return a pointer to it. The "delete[]" operator is used to deallocate memory allocated using the new operator, so it will be avalaible to the system. The square brackets mean that the pointer that you will deallocate points to an array and that not just one piece of memory with size sizeof(char) should be deallocated, but that there is an arrays which should be deallocated completeley.